# Type 'Any' has no subscript members in Swift 3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to convert my project to Swift 3 and keep getting this error. I have fixed all other errors but this one. I saw that a few other people have had problems but I am new to JSON so I didnt understand them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
class func fetchPriceForSymbol(_ symbol: String, completion:@escaping (_ stock: StockPrice) -> ()) {

    DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async {

        let url = URL(string: "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/\(symbol)/quote?format=json")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

        do {
            //let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
            let object = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let title = object["list"] as! NSDictionary
                let title2 = title["resources"] as AnyObject!
                let title3 = title2[0] as AnyObject!
                let title4 = title3["resource"] as AnyObject!
                let fields = title4["fields"] as AnyObject!


                let stockPrice = StockPrice (
                    price: fields["price"] as AnyObject! as! String
                )

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(stock: stockPrice)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle Error
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your JSON data tree? It's hard to tell what your tree looks like from just looking at your code

Comment: You are using `object` after the optional binding where it's unspecified (`Any`). Replace `object` with `dictionary`. And use `[String:Any]` rather than `NSDictionary`. And cast the objects to something more meaningful than `AnyObject`.

Comment: Specify dictionary by doing this let object = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? NSDictionary

Comment: @vadian This is the second time I've encountered you recommending the use of `[String:Any]` rather than `NSDictionary` and one of your comments was that its preferable in `Swift` but I never really understood why. Is that the `Swift` standard? If yes, but casting as `[String:Any]` is simply making a dictionary that maps a `String` to a `Any`. So why is casting it to an `NSDictionary` 'wrong'? Is there a circumstance when this might fail? Or maybe the casting might result into a weird dictionary?

Comment: @EmilDavid Short answer. Swift is based on a very strong type system. The foundation collection types don't provide any type information so it's much more convenient to use Swift native types. And Apple uses always Swift native types in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in the parsing section in the middle:

```
        let parsed = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
        let list = parsed["list"] as! [String:Any]?
        let resources = list?["resources"] as! [AnyObject]?
        let fields = resources?[0] as! [String:Any]?
        let resource = fields?["resource"] as! [String:Any]?
        let fields2 = resource?["fields"] as! [String:Any]?
        let price = fields2?["price"] as! String?
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change

```
if let dictionary = object as? [String: AnyObject]
```

with

```
if let dictionary = object as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: **Don't do that**. It makes is worse and and it doesn't solve the problem.