# Swift 3 Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I just converted my project to Swift 3 I have this line of code here:

```
let type = self.data[indexPath.row]["Type"] as? String
```

but now I get this error:

```
Type 'Any' has no subscript members
```

Why am I getting this error and do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' has no subscript members in Swift 3 Xcode 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576282/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-swift-3-xcode-8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
let type = (self.data[indexPath.row] as? [String : String])?["Type"]
```

You need to cast `self.data[indexPath.row]` to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Either your `data` or the value returned when you subscript it, e.g. `data[0]` has the `Any` type, which you're trying to subscript.

Make sure that the compiler knows that whatever you get is a known type which supports subscripting. Like and array or dictionary for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Even I was facing the same error 

for item in 0...((currentSectionCells as! NSMutableArray).count - 1) {

                if currentSectionCells[item]["isVisible"] as! Bool == true {
                }   // error "Type 'Any' has no subscript "
            }

Then changed to code as below

for item in 0...((currentSectionCells as! NSMutableArray).count - 1) {
               if (item as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "isVisible") as! Bool == true {
                }
}
```

Then it compiled without error.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question posed. The accepted answer already specified casting as a dictionary, for OP's code, your answer is both specific to your use case (not answering the question) and unsafe with force casting.