# Type any has no subscript error in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

```
    if let name = property["Name"] as? String,
      let latitude = property["Latitude"] as? NSNumber,
      let longitude = property["Longitude"] as? NSNumber,
      let image = property["Image"] as? String {

      // To learn how to read data from plist file, check out our Saving Data
      // in iOS Video Tutorial series.

      // Code goes here


    }
```

When I converted my code to current swift version, I am facing 'Type any has no subscript error'. I am fairly new to swift and stuck at this point. Saw other related posts, but no where I could find a solution for this. Please help.

Comment: [Edit] your code showing how `property` is declared and initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' has no subscript members after updating to Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480150/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-after-updating-to-swift-3)

Comment: And certainly your answer can be found amongst [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Type+any+has+no+subscript).

Comment: ... also note: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38956785/499581, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39778940/499581, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39576282/499581, http://stackoverflow.com/q/39549107/499581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I poured over the many [*questions with duplicate titles*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D%20Type%20any%20has%20no%20subscript) and couldn't find one that clearly covered your case, so I'm going to explain what is going on.

Your variable `property` is clearly declared as type `Any`, which is a variable that can hold any type.  The error message is telling you that you can't use subscripting `[]` with it.  It is clear that you believe that it is a `Dictionary` with a *key* that is a `String` and a *value* that can be anything.  In Swift 3, *anything* is typed `Any`.  So your `property` is expected to be `[String : Any]`. If you cast `property` to `[String : Any]`, then you will be able to use `[]` with it.

The first thing you should do is attempt to cast `property` to `[String : Any]` and then proceed if that works:

```
if let property = property as? [String : Any],
    let name = property["Name"] as? String,
    let latitude = property["Latitude"] as? NSNumber,
    let longitude = property["Longitude"] as? NSNumber,
    let image = property["Image"] as? String {

    // To learn how to read data from plist file, check out our Saving Data
    // in iOS Video Tutorial series.

    // Code goes here
}
```